# Unable to import module 'getApi'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, sam

I have a simple lambda function in getApi.py

```
import logging
from aws_lambda_powertools.event_handler import APIGatewayRestResolve
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
import os


logger = logging.getLogger("APP")
logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s")
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel(os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", "INFO"))

app = APIGatewayRestResolver()

@app.get("/hello")
def hello():
    logger.info("Request from hello received")
    return {"message": "hello unknown!"}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("In lambda handler")
    return app.resolve(event, context)
```

Project folder structure :

```
createApi 
   src
      getApi
          __init__.py
          getApi.py
          requirements.txt
   __init__.py
   template.yml
```

My template.yml file

```
getApiFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # Find or Create alias lambda function
    Properties:
      Handler: getApi.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64 
      Events:
        getApiApiEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: 
          Properties:
            Path:  /hello
            Method: get
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo in your import. It has to be `APIGatewayRestResolver` instead of `APIGatewayRestResolve`.

Comment: Updated the ticket with the correct error message. Thank you